# Как послать JSON в теле HTTP-запроса c параметрами на URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-form

Есть два класса:
1 класс:

```
 public class SDK {
    public  decimal amount;
    public  string  orderid;
    public  string  callbackUrl;
 }
```

Этот класс сериализуется в строку:

```
 SDK sd = new SDK();
    sd.callbackUrl = "http://Example.com";
    sd.orderid = "879564564";
    sd.amount = 8754;
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
```

2 класс:

```
public class Payer
{
    public string Id;
    public string Order;
    public string Name;
}
```

Вопрос! Как передать в телe запроса и json и параметры второго класса, методом POST, multipart/form-data на языке C#?
Спасибо!

Comment: Можно уточнить? Ваш проект будет отправлять на чужой сайт? Ваш view из js должен отправить POST на чужой сайт? На свой сайт?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19954287/5045688

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял задачу - то как-то так:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "POST";
//req.ContentType = "application/json";
using (var s = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payer);

    s.Write(json, 0, json.Length);
}

using (var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
using (var s = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var response = s.ReadToEnd();
    ...
}
```